# textView unable to display newline for string contain newline character

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I enocuntered this problem:
Problem: textView unable to display \n which contains in a string

Below code to fetch the data. The expected output will be

```
 Testing1
 Testing2
 Testing3
```

but the result display as : `Testing1\n Testing2\n Testing3`

How to setUp TextView to display newline (\n)?
In the firebase Database, I enter text with \n as newline as below.

```
 PlaceInfo
  |
  |- attractions
      |
      |- attractionName
           |
           |- about : "Testing1\n Testing2\n Testing3"
```

```
    let Ref = Database.database().reference().child("PlaceInfo")
    let myRef = Ref.child("attractions").child(strAttractionName)
    
    myRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
     
        if(snapshot.childrenCount > 0 ){
            
            guard let value = snapshot.value as? [String: String] else {
               return
            }
            
            let strAbout:String = value["about"]!
            
            self.tvPlaceDesc.text = strAbout
            
        } else {         
            print("no value")                
        }
    })
    
}
```

Comment: How were the `\n` characters entered into the string that is stored in Firebase? The characters `\n` only represent a newline when they are entered in a Swift (or C or Objective-C) string literal.

Comment: What is `TextView`? do you mean `UITextView` from UIKit? if so, it should display multi-line unless your newline characters are escaped when received from the database (e.g. if they are `\\n`, it will be displayed as `\n` and no considered a newline character.

Comment: @HangarRash I can manually enter text and \n into Firebase database. When I. fetch the data , I will get a string which has \n in it. But When I use UITextView to display it, it still show the \n instead a newline.

Comment: As I said, `\n` only has special meaning in string literals in your code. If you are typing in text somewhere then you need to enter an actual newline as part of the text, not `\n`.